# local variable 's' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

What should I do to fix this reference error? Can you aslo help me explaining why it is happening?

```
def detectobjects(image2):
    print("===== Detect Objects - local =====")
    image = open(image, "rb")
    # Call API with local image
    detect_objects_results_local = computervision_client.detect_objects_in_stream(image)
    print("Detecting objects in local image:")
    if len(detect_objects_results_local.objects) == 0:
        print("No objects detected.")
    else:
        s=""
        for object in detect_objects_results_local.objects:
            #print("Object : {} with confidence: {}".format(\object.object_property,object.confidence))            
            obj="object= {} , confidence= {} ".format(object.object_property, object.confidence)
            s+=obj
    return s
```

Comment: What isn't clear about the error? If no objects are detected, you cannot `return s`... Maybe you should fix the indentation?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `s` outside of if-else statement.

```
def detectobjects(image2):
print("===== Detect Objects - local =====")
image = open(image, "rb")
# Call API with local image
detect_objects_results_local = computervision_client.detect_objects_in_stream(image)
print("Detecting objects in local image:")
s=""
if len(detect_objects_results_local.objects) == 0:
    print("No objects detected.")
else:
    for object in detect_objects_results_local.objects:
        #print("Object : {} with confidence: {}".format(\object.object_property,object.confidence))            
        obj="object= {} , confidence= {} ".format(object.object_property, object.confidence)
        s+=obj
return s
```

Comment: This is assuming an empty string is a valid return condition instead of None

Comment: The empty string is probably fine given the string being built, though a (possibly empty) list of object/confidence strings would probably be cleaner, not if not a list of tuples. Leave it to the caller to construct a string of object/confidence pairs if desired.